# Inverse of function $y(x)=\frac1b(\ln(x+1)-x)$

Tags: lambert-w, inverse-function

I'd like to ask a question about the function below :
$$yb = ln ( x + 1 ) - x$$ I'm trying to find it's inverse. What I've tried so far : 
\begin{align}
 yb + x & = ln(x+1) \\
 e^{yb + x} & = x+1 \\ 
 e^{yb + x} - x & =  \\  
\end{align}

I'm stuck there and I don't know what to do. ${y,b}$ and ${x}$ are not whole numbers.

I've tried continuing to

\begin{align}
 e^{yb} . e^{x} - x & = 1 \\  
 e^{x} - {x\over e^{yb}}& = {1\over e^{yb} } \\ 
\end{align}

But it seems to make it worse. Any suggestion?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This one doesn't have an inverse expressible by elementary functions. Try to use [Lambert's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), though.

Comment: oh snap :S thank you for heads up, I'll take a look at Lambert's function...

Comment: Quite often, when an expression includes the variable both in and out of a transcendental function, it cannot be inverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 1 from both sides of the equation
$$yb-1 = \ln ( x + 1 ) - (x+1)$$
then set $X = x+1$ and exponentiate
$$e^{yb-1} = Xe^{-X}$$
Now substitute $Z=-X$ and get
$$-e^{yb-1} = Ze^{Z}$$
This is the standard situation for [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications) and it gives 
$$Z=W\left(-e^{yb-1}\right)$$
Undo the substitutions to have the final result
$$x=-W\left(-e^{yb-1}\right)-1$$

Comment: I tried to rearrange the equation and using Example 1 in [Wikipedia's Lambert function entry] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples) $x = - W (-e^{e^{yb} - 1}) - (1 - e^{yb})$. Your solution looks much neater, but I'll try both